# Is there a way to connect a Nokia E5 to a Win10-64 notebook, for access to 3G internet? [revised rant-free version]

Tags: tethering

Nokia E5: https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_e5-3198.php

It used to be possible on an older WinXP notebook. I have tried many times with Win10-64, with various 'suites' and extra drivers, but never quite got there. I wasn't really sure what the cause is - but I would I assume the main problem are the 64 bit.

Would it be possible with the right config and the necessary drivers - provided both are available? If you can help, could you give me a kind-of complete algorithm?

And mind you, all of you trained to react with 'smartphone' or 'hotspot': That is not desired. These european systems, as mobile ISDN subsystems, can handle ISDN-able appliances - like a modem (to which then a notebook is connected).

Comment: What "suites and extra drivers" have you tried? You need a driver to tell the computer how it is to communicate with the device and what sort of information to send and receive to and from it. Without a driver, you're stuck. Also, a note regarding our site: Questions are closed in order to allow the author to focus on fixing the question so it can be reopened. Next time, don't post a new question, correct the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Bluetooth and typically does not need any extra software.

**1. Pair the device.**

Make sure Nokia is discoverable via Bluetooth.  In the Win10 settings app, click "Devices".

[image: Win10 settings app]

Click "Add Bluetooth or other device".

[image: Add BT]

Click "Bluetooth".

[image: Bluetooth device]

Choose the E5.  A passcode appears; enter it in the E5 when prompted.

On the E5, under Bluetooth settings, go to the "Paired devices" tab, highlight the laptop, press "Options" and choose "Set as authorized".

**2. Create a dialup connection**

In the Win10 settings app, scroll down and click "Devices and printers".

[image: Devices and printers link]

Click the E5, and at the bottom of the window it should show the following:

```
Model:    Bluetooth Peripheral Device
Category: Phone, Modem
Status:   Paired
```

[image: E5 device]

The "Modem" part is required; if you do not see it, you will be unable to continue with this step.

Right-click the E5 and choose "Dial-up networking" then "Create a dial-up connection...".

[image: DUN option]

A settings window appears.

The settings depend on your SIM provider.  Typically for 3G, all you need is `*99#` in the phone number field.  Give the connection a name like "Nokia E5 3G".  Then click "Connect".

**3. Using the connection in the future**

To connect in the future, you just click the "Network" icon in the system tray and your "Nokia E5 3G" connection should be on the top of the list.

Verified to work 5 minutes ago.  The steps are quite similar to Android, so there are many helpful tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

(IT IS QUITE POSSIBLE that I don't quite understand the intention of this field. If the following should be added to my original post instead, just tell me so)

Thanks a lot! Yet what you say there sounds more like Win7 or Win8 to me, in this shape it can't be found on my Win10. Let me proceed free-style:

I haven't had trouble connecting via Bluetooth (however I can only do it over the 'suite'?). And USB connecting, as welcome alternative, used to be possible, but has stopped working (why?).

The main problem, however, seems to be that the modem can't be found, after I've configured a dialup connection?

Comment: Typically you would use this field if you are providing a solution to your own question, but never mind.  I have updated my answer with screenshots in Windows 10.  If you cannot duplicate the steps, you will need to be more precise about which step you are stuck at, and possibly a screenshot from your computer.  I cannot help you with USB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this procedure looks very target-oriented. To me it seems there are some hidden bugs at my end, maybe this is the way to sort them?

First, I switch on Bluetooth in the Nokia E5 - as such, and detectability. And I make sure not to use the 'suite'.

Then, I watch the phone's tiny Bluetooth status icon, as good as I can without a magnifying glass. I see it comes on, and then my impression is it tries to connect: The right half of the icon flashes for a second, then goes off again and remains so. I assume this means there is no active connection then? From suite operations, I know how an active connection icon looks.

The following might make limited sense only with a non-functional Bluetooth link, yet sitting here focussed on solving this problem, I go to the Bluetooth page in Win10 and find my 2 Nokia E5 listed - see photo. Intending to make a new clean start, I opt for removing them, but find it cannot be done: After some seconds of apparent trying, 'error on removing' is the system's response.

At the bottom of the Bluetooth page in Win10, there are no 'related settings' for me. Maybe it comes on during an active link? But then I see I can get there via the control panel. But there is no dialup connection in the context menu for the phone.

Also, there is no network icon in my systray, but it might come on once a connection has successfuly been created?

And again while we're at it, I find there is seemingly no 'paired devices' instance in my Nokia E5. What I do is go to control panel > settings > connection > Bluetooth, and all I see are these 4 items: Bluetooth (on/off), phone visibility, phone name, remote SIM mode.

All of this may be the result of years-long intermittent installation attempts, based on not too much knowledge/comprehension, to get it working - and surprisingly, sometimes it did  .)

Addendum: In order to possibly further pin down the causes (not certain - it might add confusion), I checked my limited collection of older/semi-useful phones and chose a Zenfone Z007. There I can connect the Win10-64 notebook and readily access the internet (3G) without any problems (there are reasons not to make this a permanent solution). Bluetooth, however, does not permit me to connect to 3G internet, although successfully paired.

PS I tried to illustrate this post with 4 photos, but didn't manage to see how this system needs to be handled, so I settled for 1 - the most important, I assume.
[image: image1]